Is the Apostrophe Necessary Here?
Is it necessary to write "university's buildings" or can I just say "university buildings" (without apostrophe)?

Both are fine.  With the apostrophe, we have a possessive noun university's; without the apostrophe, we have an attributive noun university, which functions as a modifier of buildings.

@Thuita Note this only works because "university" can describe the "type" of building. With "Rob's bicycle," you can't omit the apostrophe.
